# Can an XBee be programmed with an XBee Shield

Tags: xbee

I have an XBee and an XBee Arduino shield.

Can I program my XBee through my [Arduino Twenty-Ten](http://www.freetronics.com/products/twentyten) and an XBee shield?

Can I do anything with just one XBee?

Answer (score 2):

Recommend you get yourself one of [these](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9819).   It's well worth the price and will save you a lot of headaches.   Programming can get complex, if you're doing it manually instead of using [X-CTU](http://www.digi.com/support/kbase/kbaseresultdetl.jsp?kb=125).  Since you really only have to do it once, it's much easier to tweak the settings in X-CTU and not bother with the programming code within your application.

About the only thing you can really do with a single XBee is learn about it: fiddle with the settings and whatnot.  When you've learned all you can, you'll have to buy another one.  :)

Comment: One Explorer dongle amd 1 more XBee to come. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The XBee is a ZigBee module with a serial interface. It is designed to act as a radio communication peripheral for a microcontroller or PC.

The program code inside of the module cannot (without specialised tools) be modified, instead, you're limited to the commands listed in the [user guide](http://site.gridconnect.com/docs/MaxStream/XBee_Manual_GC.pdf).

The XBee can be controlled either [via your Arduino](http://www.ladyada.net/make/xbee/arduino.html) or with a PC and serial port.

A single unit is not very useful, unless you have access to [other ZigBee devices](http://www.zigbee.org/Products/Overview.aspx).

Comment: No, you can program in custom firmware; see section 8.5 of the [manual](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Zigbee/XBee-2.5-Manual.pdf).  The XBee modules actually have some GPIO and A/D functionality on them.  However, I think you're pretty much on your own when it comes to putting together this firmware.

Comment: for firmware help, TI would be the resource to check out http://focus.ti.com/analog/docs/rfifcomponentshome.tsp?familyId=367&contentType=4

Comment: @jsolarski so far as I know, the chip in Digi's XBee is a Freescale part running Ember ZNet, not TI

Comment: My mistake i thought the Xbee's had CCxxxx chips in them not ember.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is to put your Wireless shield in USB mode and then plug the Arduino Reset on the GND like that :

[image: Configure Arduino Uno and Wireless shield as a SparkExplorer - SIDE view]
[image: Configure Arduino Uno and Wireless shield as a SparkExplorer - TOP view]

Then you can configure your XBEE with picocom or X-CTU

**Edit**

Much more simpler, just upload this to the arduino board :

```
void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

Then set your Wireless switch on USB and that's it !

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to get XCTU to recognize the Xbee (through the Xbee Shield) by uploading that code to the board. But your first solution worked perfectly for me! Just had to connect Reset and Ground on the Arduino and start the discovery process on XCTU. Thanks!